# OpenCV - Removing noise from image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

This is my image:

[image: myimage]

I want to remove the the noise(little black unrelated pixels) from my image.
I tried `gaussian`, `cvtColor` and `adaptiveThreshold` but none did the job.
Ideas? If you have a code in java that will help.

Comment: did you try "erosion " ?

Comment: You should look at morphology operations like: opening, closing, erode, dilate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noise removal could be tricky depending on the application. for your image a simple morphology operation like closing/Opening could solve the problem. Opening operation helps to remove the noises in your image. Closing will help to fill the existing holes.

Since OpenCV c++ APIs are like Java you can use the following:

```
cv::Mat Kernel = cv::Mat(cv::Size(Maximum_Width_of_Noise,Maximum_Height_of_noise),CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(255));

cv::morphologyEx(Input_Image,temp,cv::MORPH_OPEN,Kernel);
cv::morphologyEx(temp,Output_Image,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,Kernel);
```

There are many methods but there's a trade off between accuracy/speed here.

The result of above operation is:

[image]

Comment: I set the maximum height and width equal to 3 and the result is shown above

Comment: for filling the numbers completely you can set a threshold on the final image so you get a nice and clean number .... I'm happy that I was finally managed to help someone in SO !!!!

Comment: :] well gj , i will try to smood my image as you suggested.

Comment: @omriman12 did you make it work with Java? I've tried it but is not working for me, I don't see any changes on the image.

Comment: My bad, it is working`public static void denoise(String imgInPath, String imgOutPath) {
  Mat image = Highgui.imread(imgInPath);
  Mat out = new Mat();
  Mat tmp = new Mat();
  Mat kernel = new Mat(new Size(3, 3), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255));
  Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, tmp, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
  Imgproc.morphologyEx(tmp, out, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
  Highgui.imwrite(imgOutPath, out);
 }`

Comment: Any reason `getStructuringElement` isn't used to create the kenel?